# How do I cause rails submodel join-table changes to be saved when the model is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, autosave, join

I can't figure out how to get join-table records autosaved in my app.  I am building an application to let a user make a book.  They create pages and upload a gallery of images, and then connect images to pages.  Every book has a cover page, which has a cover image.

My goal is just to be able to set the cover_image_file_name of a book, and have the submodel changes saved when the book is saved.  (I've narrowed the example so we don't deal with actual attached images - that's not a problem).

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  has_many :images, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  attr_accessible :title, :pages_attributes

  # we want to be able to set the cover page image filename for a book
  attr_accessor :cover_image_file_name

  before_validation do 
    # a book always has a cover page as page 0
    cover_page = pages.find_or_initialize_by_page_number(0)
    if @cover_image_file_name
      page_image = cover_page.page_images.find_or_initialize_by_image_type('cover')
      page_image.image = images.find_or_initialize_by_image_file_name(@cover_image_file_name)
    end
  end
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :page_images,:dependent=>:destroy
  attr_accessible :image_file_name
end
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :page_images, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  attr_accessible :page_number, :page_images_attributes
end
class PageImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :image
  attr_accessible :image_type, :image
end
```

Now, when I execute the following code to create a book and set (or reset) its cover page image, the page_image object that connects the newly created image to the cover page isn't saved:

```
book = Book.new({ title: "Book Title" })
book.save!  # this correctly saves the book and its cover page

book.cover_image_file_name = 'my_cover_page.png'
book.save!  # the image gets created and saved, but not the page_image
```

What am I missing?  I thought it might be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3610 but I am using rails 3.2.9.

Comment: You could try `has_one :cover_page, :class_name => Page'` and then `delegate :cover_image, :to => :cover_page`.  Perhaps the `Book` itself should know what it's cover page content and cover page image are, i.e. not a association, just fields on the book itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to assign **image** to **page_image** which *belongs_to :image*, the last one won't be saved. Because image (as parent object) at this moment isn't saved.

So you just have to save it before page_image can be saved with book.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  has_many :images, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  attr_accessible :title, :pages_attributes

  # we want to be able to set the cover page image filename for a book
  attr_accessor :cover_image_file_name

  before_validation do 
    # a book always has a cover page as page 0
    cover_page = pages.find_or_initialize_by_page_number(0)
    if @cover_image_file_name
      image = images.find_or_initialize_by_image_file_name(@cover_image_file_name).save
      page_image = cover_page.page_images.find_or_initialize_by_image_type('cover')
      page_image.image = image
    end
  end
end
```

The concern is that your code runs *before_validation* and save anything at this stage is wrong way. Book is not saved yet, but you already saved its content...

You have to rewrite your callback. Make it smart.